# Angular Material: How to use `mat-icon` as `mat-card-avatar` within `mat-card-header`?

Tags: angular, angular-material

Providing an image avatar within a `mat-card-header` is well supported via `mat-card-avatar`.

[image]

There are many use-cases where we'd like to use an icon, instead of an image, as the card's "avatar".

Is there an easy way to replace the avatar with an icon?

This below sort of works, but is not quite as nice as the avatar image.

[image]

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The `mat-card-avatar` directive can be applied to any element including `<mat-icon>`. You will need to apply style to the icon to get the size right:

```
<mat-card>
  <mat-card-header>
    <mat-icon mat-card-avatar>home</mat-icon>
    ...

mat-icon.mat-card-avatar {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  font-size: 40px;
}
```

Comment: I found `48px` to work better. It fits better with the default rem of `16px`.

Comment: That's your choice of course, but the Material Design specification for icons/avatars is usually 40px x 40px (e.g. an avatar on a card). Also, the style code for `mat-card-avatar` sets width and height to 40px, so making the icon larger than that might cause problems depending on how/where you use it.

Comment: You're right, I forgot I changed the height of `mat-card-title` and `mat-card-subtitle` in my project. Thus even multiples of `rem` work better for me. Ignore my comment...

Answer (score 1):

They do not alter the style automatically. One approach I used was to declare it as  and increase the font size to match the default 40px.

```
<mat-card class="example-card">
  <mat-card-header>
    <i mat-card-avatar class="material-icons">accessibility</i>
    <mat-card-title>Shiba Inu</mat-card-title>
    <mat-card-subtitle>Dog Breed</mat-card-subtitle>
  </mat-card-header>
.....
</mat-card>
```

With this, you only have to specify font-size:40px;

```
.example-card {
  max-width: 400px;

  & i {
    font-size: 40px;
  }
}
```